# Angular 10 iframe first shows 404 page then displays page content

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, angular10

Hello i am using bellow HTML code to use iframe and show an external page hosted on the same domain so no wories for cross domain

```
<iframe frameborder="0" [src]="url"></iframe>
```

and the following typescript code to sanitize and load the content

```
this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("/assets/static/page.html");
```

the problem is a bit strange after page load, the iframe first shows error 404 for a fraction of second in localhost and for a 2 to 3 seconds in production and then displays the actual page content. This is very irritating as angular has no proper support for iframe events e.g. page load, failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine you're setting the URL after the iframe has been rendered. You could try adding an `*ngIf="url"` to the iframe to delay its rendering until the URL has been set. Alternatively, try setting the URL before you render the iframe.
If that doesn't help, could you please post the code of your component?

Comment: *ngIf="url" tried this and it is not in handy, still getting the same behaviour,

Comment: also explain how i can load page before iframe rendering

Comment: If the `ngIf` doesn't work, the problem looks more like it's in the HTML page itself. Is the HTML rendered at all?Could you please post some of your code? That might make it clearer.
About the rendering: that depends on how you have set up your component. At which point in the component do you set the value? Again, some code might make this clearer. Typically, you'll need to make sure there is no change detection cycle run before you set the URL.

Comment: You above comment is the correct answer actually, thanks a lot for a great hint, a cycle change detection occurs meanwhile the URL is being loaded in the frame, after cycle completes it again attempt to load and this time shows content without interuption.

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin I'm having this same issue right now and was wondering where to look for a fix to this.

Comment: post new question with your error logs or trace or console messages you will find solution i later replaced iframe with object tag